# reading csv file in batches. Reader always misses the same line

Tags: python, csv

I have a simple python script which reads a `csv` file in batches of 5. The csv file contains a total of 9 records (excluding the header). The script bellow reads the file in batches of 5 but always seems to skip the record with `ID` 6, what am I doing wrong?

csv file:

```
"RIG_ID","STATUS_DATE"
"1","2019-04-10
"2","2019-04-11
"3","2019-04-12
"4","2019-04-13
"5","2019-04-14
"6","2019-04-15
"7","2019-04-16
"8","2019-04-17
"9","2019-04-18
```

Python script:

```
batch_size = 5
transaction_count = 0

parameter_set = []

with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:

        entry = get_entry(row)

        if(len(parameter_set) == batch_size):
            execute_transaction(sql, parameter_set)

            transaction_count = transaction_count + 1
            print(f'Transaction count: {transaction_count}')

            parameter_set.clear()
        else:
            parameter_set.append(entry)
            
    # check if we have records that didn't fit into a batch (i.e. less than 5)
    if(len(parameter_set) > 0):
        execute_transaction(sql, parameter_set)
        transaction_count = transaction_count + 1
        print(f'Transaction count: {transaction_count}')
```

If I put a breakpoint on that line `entry = get_entry(row)` after the first batch completes I get `ID = 7` thus skipping the 6th line in the csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't `append` the `entry` into your `parameter_set` when your `if` condition becomes `true`:

```
len(parameter_set) == batch_size
```

you would need to also `append` the `entry` to your `parameter_set` after you have cleared it. So i would propose:

```
         if(len(parameter_set) == batch_size):
            execute_transaction(sql, parameter_set)

            transaction_count = transaction_count + 1
            print(f'Transaction count: {transaction_count}')

            parameter_set.clear()
            parameter_set.append(entry)
        else:
            parameter_set.append(entry)
```

or to avoid duplicate code you could also move the `.append()` out of the if-else-condition because it is always executed.

```
       if(len(parameter_set) == batch_size):
            execute_transaction(sql, parameter_set)

            transaction_count = transaction_count + 1
            print(f'Transaction count: {transaction_count}')

            parameter_set.clear()
            
       parameter_set.append(entry)
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that